# Group and count in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I want a simple query to get some output. Records are

```
ID      Count
215     1
215     1
215     1
215     1
```

Output must be

```
ID   Count
215  4
```

Comment: `Count = 4` is Item Count or Sum of Value ?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM tablename
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 3):

Very simple,

```
SELECT ID ,COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT ID, sum(Count) AS Count
FROM tablename
GROUP BY ID
```